# ember-data-url-templates - how to use snapshot API with Ember 3

Tags: ember-data, ember-data-url-templates

In the add-on [wi-ki](https://github.com/amiel/ember-data-url-templates/wiki/Custom-urlSegments) it is explained that we can use belongsTo to discover the relations between models:

```
urlSegments: {
    postId: function(type, id, snapshot, query) {
      return snapshot.belongsTo('post', { id: true });
    },
  },
```

but I can't find any more in Ember 3 API docs. How to do that ?
More of that, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.belongsTo is not a function
    at Class.shopId (shop-language.js:13)
    at url-templates.js:39
    at subFunction (uri-templates.js:103)
```

when using it in an adapter:

```
#adapters/shop-language.js
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';
import UrlTemplates from "ember-data-url-templates";

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend(UrlTemplates, {
  findAllUrlTemplate: '/shops/{shopId}/languages',
  createRecordUrlTemplate: '/shops/{shopId}/languages',

  urlSegments: {
    shopId: function(type, id, snapshot, query) {
      return snapshot.belongsTo('shop', { id: true });
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to use it with `description` model that `belongsTo` a `shop`. Here is `description.js` adapter:

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';
import UrlTemplates from "ember-data-url-templates";

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend(UrlTemplates, {
  urlTemplate: '{+host}/shops/{shopId}/descriptions',
  findAllUrlTemplate: '{+host}/shops/{shopId}/descriptions',
  createRecordUrlTemplate: '{+host}/shops/{shopId}/descriptions',
  updateRecordUrlTemplate: '{+host}/shops/{shopId}/descriptions/{id}',

  urlSegments: {
    shopId: function(type, id, snapshot, query) {
      if (query && query.shop_identifier) {
        return query.shop_identifier;
      }
      return snapshot.belongsTo('shop').attr('identifier');
    },

    id: function(type, id, snapshot) {
      return snapshot.id;
    }
  }
});
```

In the above example iwas using another shop attribute - `identifier`, but you can pass in shop's `id` instead.
Hope this helps.